# Plotting a matrix in 3D With specific ticks

Tags: plotting, matrix, ticks

I have matrix and I want to plot it in 3D

```
ListPlot3D[{{3.98765, 3.9805722621093267`, 3.6669734993637384`, 
   3.547140513657327`}, {4.00978, 6.841217936322747`, 
   3.664440739410208`, 5.55098}, {4.094896872960633`, 4.36315, 
   6.327539411775844`, 3.962204146812651`}, {3.983216682983883`, 
   6.26917, 4.7494476017929514`, 16.1384}, {4.04999, 4.79856, 
   3.659365327920453`, 4.156261830970234`}, {4.059789950180353`, 
   4.014186008147935`, 4.722610902483124`, 
   5.748447432928523`}, {4.2315454107761665`, 3.76239, 3.94495, 
   3.9403001696511617`}, {4.06719, 5.18322, 4.0810431833309`, 
   3.83299}, {4.01151, 3.9015086486265798`, 20.185861947480277`, 
   5.08127}}, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.4], InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]
```

the result is as below where mathematica assumes the ticks to be natural numbers starting from one while they should be different. {1,2,3,4} should be {2,3,4,5} and {1,2,3...,8} should be {1.1,...,1.8} any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: Try `DataRange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[pts, MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.4], InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
                ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", 
                DataRange -> {{2, 5}, {1.1, 1.8}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Is this what you need? I was not sure if `{1,2,3...,8}` was refering to $y$ or $z$ axis.